# Missing $ in math mode?

Tags: errors, missing

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\det(A) = a_{11}(a_{22}a_{33} - a_{23}a_{32}) - a_{12}(a_{21}a_{33} - a_{23}a_{31}) + a_{13}(a_{21}a_{32} - a_{22}a_{31}) 
      = a_{11} \begin{vmatrix} a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{32} & a_{33} \end{vmatrix} - a_{12} \begin{vmatrix} a_{21} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{33} \end{vmatrix} + a_{13} \begin{vmatrix} a_{21} & a_{22} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} \end{vmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

(It used to be in an align environment, but I wrote the minimal example for which the code doesn't work).

I keep getting the same error:

```
Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.9 ..._{32} & a_{33} \end{vmatrix} - a_{12} 
                                                  \begin{vmatrix} a_{21} ...
```

What is wrong with a_{12} ?

Comment: When I copied your code into my example file, it came with some strange values added between the empty lines. After removing those strange symbols, it worked fine. Please check your encoding and editor settings.

Comment: You've got some spurious characters `U+000C` (form feed) in the code.

Comment: In addition, you may want to use landscape page form since it is a very long statement. Using it on normal page sense nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, how can I see those strange values? If I copy/paste my example, I don't see them...

Comment: I copy/pasted into a Unicode Text Analyzer (just google it and you'll find some). Some editors have an option "show non-printable characters" or similar.

Comment: Try to use an editor that works on UTF-8 encoding. I have been using vscode almost for everything. It has some special add-ons (free) that are totally reduce your work effort while typing latex.

Comment: Even though you may not see them in the source they are showing in the log see above where you get the [square boxes in the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkOCn.png)

Comment: Another way to find invisible symbols is to go to the indicated part of the tex source, and start pressing the right arrow key.  At the problem site, you'll press the key but nothing will happen to your cursor.  Then you can delete the invisible character that you just passed.

Comment: @eti902 "Invisible" characters are not invisible from the Emacs editor (displayed ^L). They are probably produced by software producing erroneous LaTeX code. Don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned it up a little and aligned it so it fits onto a page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{aligned}
\det(A) &= a_{11}(a_{22}a_{33} - a_{23}a_{32}) - a_{12}(a_{21}a_{33} - a_{23}a_{31}) + a_{13}(a_{21}a_{32} - a_{22}a_{31}) \\
      &= a_{11} \begin{vmatrix} 
          a_{22} & a_{23} \\ 
          a_{32} & a_{33} 
      \end{vmatrix} 
      - a_{12} 
      \begin{vmatrix} 
          a_{21} & a_{23} \\ 
          a_{31} & a_{33} 
      \end{vmatrix} 
      + a_{13} 
      \begin{vmatrix} 
          a_{21} & a_{22} \\ 
          a_{31} & a_{32} 
      \end{vmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This (and the other answer) would greatly benefit from saying that the original problem was a non-printable character.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{amsmath}

 \begin{document}

 \[
 \det(A) = a_{11}(a_{22}a_{33} - a_{23}a_{32}) - a_{12}(a_{21}a_{33} - a_{23}a_{31}) + a_{13}(a_{21}a_{32} - a_{22}a_{31}) 
 = a_{11} 
 \begin{vmatrix} a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{32} & a_{33} &
 \end{vmatrix} - a_{12} 
 \begin{vmatrix} a_{21} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{33} &
 \end{vmatrix} + a_{13} 
 \begin{vmatrix} a_{21} & a_{22} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} 
 \end{vmatrix}
 \]

 \end{document}
```

Comment: This (and the other answer) would greatly benefit from saying that the original problem was a non-printable character.